# unable to change memory allocated for AVD

Tags: android

I have installed Android Studio and trying to run hello world app using emulator.
But i am getting an error

> emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
>   emulator: device fd:596
>   HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
>   Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
>   emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.

I read on stackoverflow the solution to this problem will be to change the memory allocated to AVD.But under edit AVD's there is no such option to edit memory allocated.
Please help.

Comment: yes,  there is a edit option for  memory allocation..

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change Memory allocation settings like this:

**1. Start AVD Manager:**

**2. Click Edit Icon next to Virtual Device name**

**3. Select Advance Settings**

[image: AVD Settings]

**4. In Advance Settings, there is option to edit memory allocation**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harsh! i missed scrolling under Advanced settings! :(

Comment: I just tried this solution but I am still having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[image: see this snap below]
  - >Go to avd manager
  - > Click edit optoin
  - > Change Memory Options